# Can anyone tell me what does -L and -l do?

Tags: linux, makefile, terminal

I have a makefile as follow, but im not quite sure what -L and -l does

```
all: main.cpp
   cd nodelib && make
   g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -I nodelib/inc -L nodelib/ -lnode
```

for reference my code is structured as the following:

```
./ 
 main.cpp 
 makefile 
 nodelib/ 
   makefile 
   inc/ 
     Node.hpp 
     Set.hpp 
   src/ 
     Node.cpp 
     Set.cpp 
     makefile
```

the makefile in src creates an archive `libnode.a` and then moves it to the parent directory `nodelib`

im especially confused with the `-lnode` part, as in the directories there are no files named `node`. Tried changing it to `-lNode` as the `Node` file in the source directory is named with a capital N, but that only made the makefile have an error. But makefile works fine if i change it back to `-lnode`

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -I nodelib/inc -L nodelib/ -lNode
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lNode
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:5: main.exe] Error 1
```

Thanks in advance and i really appreciate the answers!

Comment: Did you try reading the docs? https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html

Comment: -L specifies the library path. -l specifies the libraries to link in. `g++ --help` FTW!

Comment: Compiler options have nothing to do with make...

Comment: the GNU Make manual will tell you everything you need to know https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for `-l`, from [GCC's `info` on command line options for linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html):

> `-llibrary`
>
> `-l library`
>
> Search the library named *library* when linking. (The second alternative with the library as a separate argument is only for POSIX compliance and is not recommended.)
>
> The `-l` option is passed directly to the linker by GCC. Refer to your linker documentation for exact details. The general description below applies to the GNU linker.

Documentation for `-L`, from [GNU ld's `info`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html):

> `-L searchdir`
>
> `--library-path=searchdir`
>
> Add path *searchdir* to the list of paths that `ld` will search for archive libraries and `ld` control scripts. You may use this option any number of times. The directories are searched in the order in which they are specified on the command line. Directories specified on the command line are searched before the default directories. All `-L` options apply to all `-l` options, regardless of the order in which the options appear.